# ZipFile.CreateFromDirectory UnauthorizedAccessException

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, zip, .net-5

I am trying to create a Zip File in .NET 5.0 using the following Syntax:

```
ZipFile.CreateFromDirectory(sourceDirectoryName, zipFilePath, CompressionLevel.Fastest, true);
```

The Problem is, that there is a Subdirectory that I have no Read Access to. Thus I am always getting a `UnauthorizedAccessException` and the zipping process aborts. Is there any way to skip this unauthorized folder?

Answer (score 1):

As you can see from [the source code for `ZipFile.CreateFromDirectory`](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/1a84b29e367493c50dc979d7897a386734b8fd7f/src/libraries/System.IO.Compression.ZipFile/src/System/IO/Compression/ZipFile.Create.cs#L354-L422), there aren't any arguments you can supply to suppress that exception.

```cs
public static void CreateFromDirectory(
    string sourceDirectoryName, 
    string destinationArchiveFileName, 
    CompressionLevel compressionLevel, 
    bool includeBaseDirectory, 
    Encoding? entryNameEncoding) =>
        DoCreateFromDirectory(
            sourceDirectoryName, 
            destinationArchiveFileName, 
            compressionLevel, 
            includeBaseDirectory, 
            entryNameEncoding);

private static void DoCreateFromDirectory(
    string sourceDirectoryName, 
    string destinationArchiveFileName,
    CompressionLevel? compressionLevel, 
    bool includeBaseDirectory, 
    Encoding? entryNameEncoding) { ... }
```

This leaves you a couple of options:

1. [Copy the method](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/1a84b29e367493c50dc979d7897a386734b8fd7f/src/libraries/System.IO.Compression.ZipFile/src/System/IO/Compression/ZipFile.Create.cs#L354-L422) and make necessary edits to suit your needs.
2. Walk the tree, make a list of all accessible files, then use `ZipFileUtils.EntryFromPath` to manually craft a ZIP archive.
3. Copy/hardlink all files you want to zip to a temporary folder while skipping inaccessible files and zip that folder instead.